# Use Array as function call arguments

Tags: go

In JavaScript, you can use `.apply` to call a function and pass in an array/slice to use as function arguments.

```
function SomeFunc(one, two, three) {}

SomeFunc.apply(this, [1,2,3])
```

I'm wondering if there's an equivalent in Go?

```
func SomeFunc(one, two, three int) {}

SomeFunc.apply([]int{1, 2, 3})
```

The Go example is just to give you an idea.

Comment: Go is not a dynamic language and you shouldn't really need to do that kind of thing in Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called variadic functions and use the `...` syntax, see [Passing arguments to ... parameters](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters) in the language specification.

An example of it:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func sum(nums ...int) (total int) {
    for _, n := range nums { // don't care about the index
        total += n
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    many := []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

    fmt.Printf("Sum: %v\n", sum(1, 2, 3)) // passing multiple arguments
    fmt.Printf("Sum: %v\n", sum(many...)) // arguments wrapped in a slice
}
```

[Playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/KhbSwhCu79)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually found out about this a few hours later, surprised I hadn't tried it before. It seems obvious when you know.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using reflection, specifically [`Value.Call`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Call), however you really should rethink why you want to do that, also look into interfaces.

```
fn := reflect.ValueOf(SomeFunc)
fn.Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(10), reflect.ValueOf(20), reflect.ValueOf(30)})
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/-ynLESCvKl)

Comment: What do you suggest with Interfaces?

Comment: @daryl I meant you should think why you need to use this kind of dynamic calling and see if you can replace it with an interface.

Comment: @OneOfOne this is the wrong solution, think thrice before you ever import reflect and especially when suggesting others to do so. See AndrewN's answer for the correct thing to do.

Comment: @Wessie It's the right the solution for the question, it is the closest thing to function.apply in javascript, Andrew's solution would only work for one type.